# RadImageEditor toolbar buttons now shoring

Tags: c#, telerik

Why are the toolbar buttons not showing in my radimageeditor I followed the example but dont understand why they not rendering

http://snag.gy/WAYtX.jpg

Comment: Which example have you followed? Which technology are you using - ASP.NET AJAX, Silverglight, any other? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried removing all custom CSS from the page? Do all requests return successfully?